# Delphi5 DirectoryExists()

Tags: delphi, directory, delphi-5

I'm using D5 on Win2000 but building applications for all platforms.

I can use `FileExists` in my D5 application but `DirectoryExists` is an undeclared identifier.

They both come from the SysUtils.Pas which I have put in my Use list. Can anyone suggest how I  use this function and if not how can I work around it?

Comment: What makes you think they both come from *SysUtils.pas*? Do you *see* them both in that unit? What units *do* you see them in? Have you looked?

Comment: This is a question that could have easily been answered by using a Find In Files to search the source code. Whilst you have the answer now you should learn how to work this stuff out for yourself.

Comment: Sorry guys I just read the SysUtils off this http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=DirectoryExists page and assumed it was for D5 too. I'll look harder next time :p

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `DirectoryExists` function is declared in the `FileCtrl` unit.

Comment: You were faster :-D (I didn't trust my memory)

Answer (score 5):

DirectoryExists lives in the FileCtrl unit in D5.